# how to access settings variable from different project in the same folder in django

Tags: python, django, caching

I have different projects under one folder in django. I am trying to get all caches variables from each settings.py to be displayed in one project A. So far, I have been able to access the local settings in A. 
  Using something like

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
from django.conf import settings
def get_cache_settings():
    return settings.CACHES.keys()
```

Then I tried the following to get the settings from B but didn't work

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
from B.django.conf import settings
```

also tried

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->
from B import django.conf.settings
```

The tree folder look like this:

```
Project/
       A/
         cache/
              urls.py
              view.py
         settings.py
       B/
         settings.py
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Plese,post your project folder tree and locate settings.py into it. When I create a project, a new folder that contains settings is created.

Comment: @danihp, my mistake, A and B are actually projects not app. So I am trying to get the cache settings from the project B in A to be displayed. I was thinking to write a script that do it, open the files, ... but if there is an easier way would love to hear about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django settings are project level, so there is no such thing as app settings.

If you are talking about a settings.py file living in app directory A, just:

```
from A import settings as A_settings
```

Comment: o ok, Thanks. Actually A would be a project and B would be another under a big folder but they are inter-related. I tried your suggestion but didn't work. any other suggestions? @ThomasOrozco

Comment: If you have several projects not apps, then it's a different issue. 

I suggest that you modify the settings file themselves (they are regular python files) so as to load a common file where your common data would be (using an import and possibly path modification)

Comment: +1 for Thomas's comment. This approach also has the benefit of making it much easier for you to change any settings you need to change without having remember where they are located and then tracking them down.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add your bigger folder to your python path.

```
$export PYTHONPATH=..:$PYTHONPATH
```

now you can do

```
from A import settings as A_settings

from B import settings as B_settings
```